# TypeError: Rect argument is invalid

Tags: python

Помогите пожалуйста
Мой код :

```
from turtle import width

import pygame

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

pygame.display.set_caption("Cubes")

x = 50
y = 50
widht = 40
height = 60
speed = 5

run = True
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(100)

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 255), (x, y, width, height))
    pygame.display.update()
```

ошибка

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/GAMES_2/GAme#1/Cubes Game.py", line 23, in <module>
    pygame.draw.rect(win, (0, 0, 255), (x, y, width, height))
TypeError: Rect argument is invalid
```

Помогите пожалуйста

Comment: А вот это там зачем `from turtle import width`? Вроде бы и не должно в итоге мешать, но это плохо, когда у вас переменные называются так же, как какие-то штуки из библиотек, могут быть разные неожиданности в итоге.

Answer (score 0):

А, ну точно - вы передаёте в pygame.draw.rect вместо ширины из переменной, которая у вас называется `widht`, функцию, импортированную из библиотеки: `from turtle import width`. Именно эта вторая `width` попадает в `(x, y, width, height)`. Естественно, Python ругается, что была передана функция вместо целого числа.
В общем-то это частая ошибка начинающих - либо называть переменные так же как ключевые слова Python-а, либо ещё как-то путать разные сущности.
В данном случае вы немного перепутали написание и получили две разных сущности, одну из которых использовали вместо другой, не заметив этого.

Comment: стоит уточнить, чтобы  избежать ошибки, надо переименовать какой-либо widht, например ```from turtle import width``` -> ```from turtle import t_width```

Comment: @Александр Да я вообще не понял, зачем здесь turtle, сначала автору вопроса надо разобраться, что у него там происходит в целом :)

Comment: Александр после выполнения действий по вашему совету выходит следующая ошибка: ImportError: cannot import name 't_width' from 'turtle' (D:\GAMES_2\python\lib\turtle.py)

Comment: @JluMoH4uk Попробуйте вообще убрать этот import из turtle, он вам там нужен? И переименуйте свою переменную правильно - в width, а не widht

Comment: Да, зачем вам нужен turtle ? Поправлюсь надо было исправить на ```from turtle import width as t_width```

Comment: Спасибо всем за советы особенно Александру!